# Show that $h(x) = 1_H$ for each $x \in G$ - Factorisation into homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $O(G)=60$, $O(H)=12$ and consider we can factorise into homomorphisms $h: G \to H$ as $h=g \circ f$, where $f: G \to K$ and $g: K \to H$ and $O(K)=35$. Show that $h(x) = 1_H$ for each $x \in G$.

I think here $H < K < G, and we could use the Lagrange theorem. Is anyone can help me to solve this problem? This is an exercise that I want to achieve to better understand the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f: G\to H$ is a homormorphism, and $g\in G$ has order $k$, then
$$e_H = f(e_G) = f(g^k) = f(g)^k$$
so the order of $f(g)$ must divide $k$.

In particular, if $\#G$ and $\#H$ are coprime, then can you use this to deduce that $f$ is trivial?

Returning to your question, what does this tell you about the homomorphism $g:K\to H$?

Answer (score 0):

if K be a subgroup at G then the order of K must divide order of G but o(K)=35 .